# spring jboss deploy IllegalAccessError

Tags: spring

War application. Deploy in jboss 5. Error deploy.

The application uses spring (with maven) .

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>


        <struts2.version>2.3.16</struts2.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.integration.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <hibernate.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate.version>
        <quartz.version>2.1.6</quartz.version>


    </properties>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
....
```

the error at deploy  in  server log

```
2015-12-03 12:10:27,309 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/MCCPlus]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.setBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.<init>(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:57)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:830)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:470)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:313)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is you are mixing different versions of Spring which are incompatible.
You should now have versions that work together and no conflicting versions.
And verify you don't have some old versions of Spring JAR files around in your classpath.